# How does node work with Yarn Plug-n-Play?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Yarn 2.0 is bringing PnP to the table, but I don't really understand how I can run javascript with the simple `node` command anymore if the file has dependencies in the npm registry. `node` looks for `node_modules` folders to find dependencies, but since PnP removes the `node_modules` folder entirely, do I need to use a command other than `node` now? Or will node introduce some new flag to read the `.pnp.js` file instad of recursively looking upwards for the nearest `node_modules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yarn node index.js`. See the yarn 2 (berry) docs. https://yarnpkg.com/cli/node

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Yarn 2 PnP docs:

> Because Node had no concept of packages, it also didn't know whether a file was meant to be accessed (versus being available by the sheer virtue of hoisting). It was entirely possible that the code you wrote worked one day in development but broke later in production because you forgot to list one of your dependencies in your package.json.

**For your answer** that can you can you run using command `node index.js`.

You need to add a script in your `package.json` scripts section like `"start": "node index.js"` and then run `yarn run start`

Comment: Yes this should work too as long as you're using yarn to run the script. I think if you try and use npm to run the script it won't work.